# I don't understand the difference in EXPLAIN output between two queries. The only difference is LEFT JOIN vs. INNER JOIN in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

These two queries are identical except for LEFT JOIN vs. INNER JOIN. Notice the EXPLAIN on the LEFT JOIN mentions a key for a column that is not used at all in the query: megastore.

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT m.imdbid
     , uma.multiplier 
  from movies m 
  LEFT 
  JOIN ur_movie_actors uma 
    ON uma.imdbid = m.imdbid 
   AND uma.user_uuid = '11e9';

+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys         | key       | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | index | NULL                  | metascore | 3       | NULL | 106764 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | uma   | NULL       | ALL   | user_uuid,user_imdbid | NULL      | NULL    | NULL |  24750 |    50.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+

EXPLAIN 
SELECT m.imdbid
     , uma.multiplier 
  from movies m 
  JOIN ur_movie_actors uma 
    ON uma.imdbid = m.imdbid 
   AND uma.user_uuid = '11e9';

+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys         | key       | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | uma   | NULL       | ref    | user_uuid,user_imdbid | user_uuid | 38      | const | 12375 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,imdbID        | PRIMARY   | 29      | func  |     1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
```

I don't understand what is going on here except maybe I have database corruption?

Comment: That's a fundamental difference

Comment: Complete CREATE TABLE scripts for both tables must be provided. Also table statistic (total rows amount, rows amount matched each separate condition and each condition combination) must be provided too.

Comment: Remember - when the amount of filtered rows is over approx. 5-7% then table scan is more suitable than the index usage.

Comment: `left join` and `inner join` are different things. As you noted in a comment to your first question, *"I want to add every MOVIE record whether there is a MOVIE_RATINGS record or not."*. Thus, it's not surprising that for a left join, MySQL has to read every movie record whether there is a MOVIE_RATINGS record or not. For an inner join, it doesn't. Which is a) why you  took `left join` b) why MySQL does not have to execute the queries in the same way c) why you get different results and d) why the explain output is different. So since you mentioned database corruption twice now: it isn't.

Comment: Thanks! One more question. Can anyone explain why the KEY for the first query shows the column "metascore" even though that column is not mentioned in the SELECT statement and other columns (like imdbID) ARE mentioned and are indexed?